# React: How does React make sure that useEffect is called after the browser has had a chance to paint?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The documentation for useLayoutEffect says:

> Updates scheduled inside useLayoutEffect will be flushed
>   synchronously, before the browser has a chance to paint.

the documentation for useEffect says:

> Unlike componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate, the function passed
>   to useEffect fires after layout and paint, during a deferred event.

how does React check when the layout and paint has happened and when is the right time to call useEffect ?
A hack that i have used often in to use setTimeout 0 for such scenarios, but i am interested in understanding how React implements this? (SetTimeout, requestAnimationFrame ?)

Comment: I just figged through the react source, still I could not find the relevant part ... All I did find was `ReactDOM.__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED` :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

They use `postMessage` (in combination with `requestAnimationFrame`):

```
  // We use the postMessage trick to defer idle work until after the repaint.
```

Found in 
[React/scheduler/src/forks/SchedulerHostConfig.default.js](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/4189f712c16cfd6365c163525527a30ef2518b99/packages/scheduler/src/forks/SchedulerHostConfig.default.js#L234)

`setTimeout` can't be used as it will be throttled if used recursively. `requestAnimationFrame` can't be used by itself as that gets triggered *right before the repaint*. Now if you however post a message to the page itself right before the repaint using `postMessage`, then that callback will run directly after the repaint.

```
 const channel = new MessageChannel();

 channel.port1.onmessage = function() {
  console.log("after repaint");
 };

 requestAnimationFrame(function () {
   console.log("before repaint");
   channel.port2.postMessage(undefined);
 });
```

Comment: What would be the problem with setTimeout? Is there a scenario where we would expect this functionality to be called recursively? If it throttles, are the "after repaint" calls would be delayed? But would we still be sure that setTimeout would happen after the paint?

Comment: setTimeout callbacks are not related to painting, thats what requestAnimationFrame is for. However it can't be used like `postMessage` as `setTimeout(callback, 0)` would get throttled to a few milliseconds.